# Jquery Ajax only works when in debug mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to teach myself MVC and jquery, but seem to be having problems posting data back to my controller via ajax.  My idea was to display a list of type MealViewModel in my EditMenu view, then use a bootstrap modal to display a partial view when the chef wanted to insert a new meal or edit a meal.  I haven't made it to the edit part yet.

Here is my EditMenu view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.MealViewModel>
@using Test.Utilities;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Menu";
}
<div class="container">
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Insert New Meal ", "InsertMeal", "Chef", null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary" })
    <br /><br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MealDescription)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MealDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MealType)
           </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Edit",
                    actionName: "EditMeal",
                    controllerName: "Chef",
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-primary" },
                    routeValues: new { mealId = item.MealId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
                $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
            });

            $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
                $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
            });

            $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            });

           $('#cancel-button').on('click', function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

Here is my _EditMeal partial view, which is rendered in the bootstrap modal.

```
@model Test.Models.MealViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h1 class="modal-title">Create New Meal</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="insertForm">
            <div class="form-horizontal">

               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-md-2">Description: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" id="meal-description" class="form-control" name="description" />
                   </div>
                </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Date:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input id="meal-date" class="form-control" type="date" name="date" />
                   </div>
               </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Type:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select id="meal-type" class="form-control" name="type">
                            <option value="Breakfast">Breakfast</option>
                            <option value="Dinner">Dinner</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                       <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default submitMeal" id="submit-button" />
                    </div>
                </div>

           </div>
        </form>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $("#submit-button").on('click', function () {

        var meal = {
            "MealDescription": $("#meal-description").val(),
            "MealDate": $("#meal-date").val(),
            "MealType": $("#meal-type").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("InsertMeal", "Chef")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(meal),
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my controller:

```
    // Insert new meal
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertMeal(MealViewModel newMeal)
    {
        repo.InsertMeal(newMeal);

        List<MealViewModel> allMeals = repo.GetAllMeals().ToList();

        return View("EditMeal", allMeals);
    }
```

Everything seems to work, but only when inserting `debugger;` in the script tag in the _EditMenu view and stepping through my code.  I've spent some time on Google trying to find a solution, but I have come up empty.  I've tried adding `cache: false` to the ajax post, used `@Url.Action()` to properly render the url, but nothing seems to work.  As soon as I exit debug mode, the ajax call never hits my controller and fails every time.  Why does my ajax post only work when debugging?

Note: Bootstrap, Jquery, jquery.validate, and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax are all bundled and render on my shared _layout page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not cancelling the submit action of the form so it will post back.

```
$("#submit-button").on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDeafult();
```

Also when you make the Ajax call, you do nothing with the response.

Comment: I read that on another post, but it dint make sense to me at the time.  It does now.  Thank you.